# How do I store a realtime video timestamp into mysql database

Tags: mysql, ajax, wistia

I have a Wistia video where I am getting the current timestamp of the video every one second using their API, storing it into local storage and then getting those items into hidden input field.

I want to be able to use AJAX so that it can get the values from those hidden input boxes and store them into MySQL every second or so. Any help would be appreciated - I am no developer but stepping in as the senior developer is on holiday.